# How can I solve scratch2 textbox problem for rtl languages like farsi?

Tags: right-to-left, mit-scratch, farsi, block-programming

I'm using scratch 2.0 and for RTL languages such as farsi and arabic , I've got a problem with Textboxes . You can see the problem I face in picture below, starting the sentence from left to right.
It'd be helpful if you guys can help me out.
Is it related to Adobe Air version ?
I tried modifying locale/fa.po file but the problem in text box's still there !
Thank you in advance :)

[SCRATCH2 TEXTBOX PROBLEM PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qRJ2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The text box will disappear once you enter something in the input field then press Enter.